# Bind custom directive to host

Tags: angular

I've looked far and wide but I can't seem to find an answer.  I've created a directive, which works fine, but I want to bind it to the host of a component dynamically.

Example:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'myDirective' })

@Component({ selector: 'myComponent',
    template: 'some content goes here...'
})
export class MyComponent {
    /* bind myDirective to host */
}

//when using myComponent, it should be
<myComponent></myComponent>
//not
<myComponent myDirective></myComponent>
```

I basically want to remove the need to either a) explicitly set `myDirective` and b) wrap the template with an element just to use `myDirective`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is currently not supported.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785

Comment: Apparently, it is going to be supported it in v15 (see issue linked above)

Comment: @Elanor-L bit step \o/

Answer (score 6):

6 and half yars later:

With Angular 15 you can:
https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api

In your case:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'myDirective', standalone: true })
export class ...
```

```
@Component({ selector: 'myComponent',
    template: 'some content goes here...',
    hostDirectives: [myDirective],
})
export class MyComponent {
}
```

Your `myDirective` must be `standalone: true` (another new thing in Angular15).
Meaning - still no `FormControlName` inside your component