# Angular 6 Nested Directives

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to nest directives in my angular 6 application (the typescript version of angular). In other words: from within directive *A* I would like to apply 2 other directives *B* and *C*.

Directives have no templates so I'm not sure if this is possible or not. Also, inheritance is not sufficient since I would have to inherit from multiple directives.

Is this possible or do I have to bite the bullet and have duplicate code?

---

If you are wondering why I would like to do this read on:

I have directives for **right click** events such as mouse down, mouse up. The input to these directives is a function that gets called on these events.

I want to create a right click drag directive such that the inputs are functions to handle the following right-click events: on mouse down, on mouse up, and optionally on drag.

I know how to do this building the directive from scratch but it would be cleaner if I could simply use the existing directives for right click mouse down etc.

I could then create more complicated drag directives that handle dom manipulation by leveraging the already existing right-drag directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sadly, it looks like this is not possible at this point.**

There is currently a feature request here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785

If you would like to see this feature implemented please give the issue a thumbs up so it gets more attention!

See also: [Angular2 - Bind Custom Directive To Host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37513283/2509290)

---

The closest thing available to modifying the host item is using the host parameter to the directive annotation. This appends classes, events, etc to the host component. Unfortunately it does not support appending custom directives.

**Hopefully in the future** they will extend the host functionality to support the following:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[custom-directive-a]',
    host: {
        // Currently not supported 
        //   but should append custom directives to host component
        'custom-directive-b': ' ',
        'custom-directive-c': ' ' 
    }
})
```